# How to download a file from shared folder in onedrive using c#?

Tags: c#, onedrive

I want to download a file from shared folder in my OneDrive using c#

```
WebClient clientDownload = new WebClient();

StringBuilder requestUri= new StringBuilder();

requestUriDownload2.AppendFormat("https://onedrive.live.com/download?resid={0}",FileId);

clientDownload.DownloadFile(requestUriDownload2.ToString(), @"C:\Users\Junior\Desktop\exammple.zip");
```

Comment: and your problem is...?

Comment: i want to know how to get download link from files in shared folder for use DownloadFile method

Comment: @JuniorOliveira Please add that information, as well as what behavior you are currently getting to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any authentication or authorization logic in your code. Do you have that?

Comment: I have a authorization in my code, the user make log in in my program, i want to know how to get download link from files in shared folder for use DownloadFile method.